# Spring data jpa add filter/interceptor

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have used hibernate before, and have successfully added a filter that would intercept saves and entities who implemented a certain interface would have something logged.

Is it possible to do something similar in the new Spring Data, I have just started out using it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can always add filters/interceptors with spring data

Following is an example:

```
<bean id="customizableTraceInterceptor" class="
  org.springframework.aop.interceptor.CustomizableTraceInterceptor">
  <property name="enterMessage" value="Entering $[methodName]($[arguments])"/>
  <property name="exitMessage" value="Leaving $[methodName](): $[returnValue]"/>
</bean>

<aop:config>
  <aop:advisor advice-ref="customizableTraceInterceptor"
    pointcut="execution(public * org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository+.*(..))"/>
</aop:config>
```

reference: http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/