# Spring Data Repository handle null results or entity reading permissions

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I've managed to get Spring Data JPA up and running with my current project. Everything has been going fairly smooth up until now.

I was wondering, is there a way to handle Spring Data Repository responses inside the actual Repository/Base repository implementation? (Or perhaps in an interceptor?)

**For instance:** I have the need to check if any results were returned from my repository methods, and throw an exception if not like so:
(Preferably keeping the 'magic' of Spring data and not having to implement every repository method)

```
public interface MyRepository<T,ID> extends CrudRepository<T,ID> {
    List<T> findByName(String name);
}
```

In this case I'd want to throw an exception if the resulting `List<T>` was null/empty.

**Example 2:** I have the need to check permission to read, to make sure I have the right to read the requested object from the database. Same thing goes here, I want to inspect / intercept the repository result and find out if the entity instance is the right one considering my context. (For security reasons)

**TL;DR** Is there any way of "intercept"/inspect the resulting entities/list from a repository method without having to implement ALL magic `findBy...` methods from all repositories? Perhaps in the base repository implementation or via an interceptor of some kind?

Regards

**EDIT** I have seen the answer in [this particular SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824173/spring-data-jpa-add-filter-interceptor) and I was wondering if there's another way of doing it, which doesn't involve the use of a custom implemented `MethodInterceptor`?
Regards

Comment: That's roughly what  a service in front of the repository does most of the time. Very unmagical but also a clean separation between your application logic and the actual raw repository

Comment: @zapl Yes I can see that it would be. However, implementing a service for each repository just to be able to empty/null check seems a bit over the top.

Comment: You can configure an interceptor yes, see the linked duplicate. It mentions a logging interceptor but you can have your own and inspect the method return value.

Comment: @Tunaki That looks promising. Is there a possibility to intercept only the repository methods and not those of "CrudRepository" interface?

Comment: Yes, you can tweak the pointcut used (not use `JpaRepository` but your own interface).

Comment: @Tunaki Altough the linked answer is one solution, I'm wondering if there's another way of doing this which doesn't require a custom `MethodInterceptor`. Perhaps something built-in to Spring Data? Please re-open the question as I've edited it.